# Codeception and MongoDb. Configuration file

Tags: mongodb, codeception

I would like test some data by codeception. And I don't know, how should correct set 'dns' in configuration file. I try this, but I get connection error

```
- MongoDb:
      dsn: 'host=127.0.0.1:27017;dbname=test'
      user: 'root'
      password: ''
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this config in your codeception.yml file

```
modules:
   MongoDb:
      dsn: mongodb://host:port/database
```